# Dish For Tracking and Communicating with ISS

Tags: iss

It is already mentioned that ISS orbit the earth 15 times a day, how we design a dish network to stay communicate with it along its path? Are we build a dish in Atlantic Ocean too?

Comment: Check out TDRS...

Comment: they have a fixed a dish on earth, but a dynamic dish on ISS?

Answer (score 5):

NASA communicates with the ISS through their Space Network, which consists of a constellation of satellites including ones in geosynchronous orbit, low earth satellites, and ground facilities that relay between NASA and the satellites.  It's available 24/7 and allows constant communication with the ISS, including voice, telemetry, etc.

More at: https://www.nasa.gov/directorates/heo/scan/services/networks/sn

Answer (score 4):

While the Apollo-era space program had to rely on ground stations for communication, a network of geostationary satellites called [TDRSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracking_and_data_relay_satellite) has been in use since the 1980s to provide continuous communication with spacecraft in orbit (as well as to the south pole!).

Comment: but, how about this question:
How NASA directed a rocket during launcing the first geostationer satellite, there is no other satellite for it to communicate?

Comment: Why would you need a satellite? We have had radios for a long time, long before there were satellites.

Comment: I don't know exactly how TDRS-1 was guided into position, but almost certainly it was through some combination of communication from ground stations, ships at sea, and onboard automation.

Comment: TDRSS is not used for guidance.  TDRS-1 was launched on a IUS which used inertial guidance. https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/6.1978-1292 https://www.globalsecurity.org/space/systems/ius.htm

Comment: I mean, it is difficult to make a dish keep track with ISS, because ISS orbitting  the earth  15 a day, so they must build a dish with specialized motor to track it. But why in ISS they can build that? I mean ISS must communicate with a network of Geostationary satellite, so its must be equipped with specialized dish with a motor so it can track where TDRS satellite located.